# How to filter {CR} from Gen2 CSV file in ADF

Tags: database, csv

Is there a way to filter {CR} from the data while writing it into a Gen2 CSV file?

Details:
I did create a ADF pipeline, this uses CopyData activity, {LR} as row delimiter, reads data from a DB,  and write data into the Gen2 CSV file.

Couple of source string columns will have {CR} and needs to be filtered.

I need to use this ADF pipeline to create multiple files, having different row formats.

Thanks in advance for your valuable suggestions.

Comment: Could you explain in detail with sample data and desired result?

Comment: Source data in DB:
Rno|Ino|Iname
764|O04|Oil for Schooters{LR}
134|S003|Shampoo {CR} 5ml{LR}
711|S811|Shoes for kids, size 7 {CR} or size 6
492|O34|Sunflower oil{CR}filtered 5ltr


Data file generated with data issue:
Rno|Ino|Iname
764|O04|Oil for Schooters{LR}
134|S003|Shampoo 
{CR} 5ml{LR}
711|S811|Shoes for kids, size 7 
{CR} or size 6
492|O34|Sunflower oil
{CR}filtered 5ltr


Expected data file:
Rno|Ino|Iname
764|O04|Oil for Schooters{LR}
134|S003|Shampoo  5ml{LR}
711|S811|Shoes for kids, size 7  or size 6
492|O34|Sunflower oil filtered 5ltr

Comment: I could not attach a file or screensnip, so posted sample data above.